# Is there any Solution for this Login syntax>?

Tags: python, django

Ive this Django Login and Registration form
but the registration form is fetching in database auth_user but not in helloworld_register
This is my Registration code

```
def Register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
          username=request.POST['username']
          email=request.POST['email']
          first_name=request.POST['first_name']
          last_name=request.POST['last_name']
          password1=request.POST['password1']
          password2=request.POST['password2']
          if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
             messages.info(request, 'uh oh..:(   This Email is Already Taken ')
             print('emailtaken')
             return redirect('/Register')
            
          elif User.objects.filter(first_name=first_name).exists():
               messages.info(request, 'uh oh..:(  This Name is Already Taken  ')
               print('Name taken')
               
               return redirect('/Register')
              
             
                 
          user=User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,password=password1)
          user.save();
          messages.info(request, 'Registration complete Login to continue ..:)')
          print('user created')
          
          return redirect('/LOGIN')
    return render(request, 'Register.html')
```

And this is my Login Code

```
def LOGIN(request):
      if request.method=='POST':
          email=request.POST['email']
          password1=request.POST['password1']
          user=auth.authenticate(email=email,password1=password1)
          
          #user.save();
          if user is not None:
              auth.LOGIN(request,user)
              return redirect('LOGIN')
          else:
                messages.info(request, 'mmm :( Invalid Credentials ')
                return redirect('LOGIN')
```

Even though if i try Logging in with registered credentilals im unable to login

Comment: please add traceback error message

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to correct the terminology. Both snippets you provided are not Forms but **Views**. And 'auth_user' is not a database, its a **table**, as I will assume for 'helloworld_register'.

Related to your first problem, it seems that you are using Django's default User model. And by default this model uses 'auth_user' both to create and retrieve objects.

If you want to change defaults, you are going to need a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), in fact here is a quote from Django documentation about such:

> If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a
> custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for
> you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but
> you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises

As for your second issue, take a look at this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in). I see a few errors in your snippet, such as:

```
user=auth.authenticate(email=email,password1=password1)
# there is no field password1 in the User model.

if user is not None:
    auth.LOGIN(request,user) # Wrong call do login() method
    return redirect('LOGIN') # You want to redirect to some other place
```

Therefore you are probably looking for something like this:

**(Also, do not ignore good practices such as views names in snake_case)**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect

    def my_view(request):
        email= request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password1']
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            redirect('/your/app/index')
            
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'mmm: Invalid Credentials.')
            redirect('/back/to/login')
```